# How to add second application to MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Say I've got an MVC website, `www.codesmurf.com` for example, set up with default ASP.NET MVC routing, nothing fancy. So my `BlogController` can be found at `www.codesmurf.com/blog`, and my `FAQ` similarly at `www.codesmurf.com/faq`.

Now if I also have a small survey project, currently in a different solution, how would I achieve to access this survey at `www.codesmurf.com/survey`?

What changes would I have to make to my routing and/or project structure to achieve this? So the entire survey project would be at the controller level of the main website, judging by the uri.

Do I have to achieve this using `Areas`? Do I need to create a `SurveyController` on the main site to redirect internally? Do I need to host this website separately and redirect externally? Any IIS configurations? How do I make sure my old routing isn't messed up?
This seemed like an easy task in my head at first, but I really have no clue what the best way to achieve this would be, and questions keep popping up in my head the more I think about it.

Note that the survey site is also an MVC project with its own controllers etc..

I haven't had much experience with changing the MVC routes, but would like to understand what I'm doing as well, so context/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would add the survey functionality as a service reference to your current MVC project.

Add Areas/Survey to your current MVC project and then start using the code from the service reference as you build up the Survey area.

When adding areas, all you will need to do is add some more rules to your map routes.

`routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`